# LNK2019 on a solution with a dll project

Tags: c++, dll, linker-errors

I am trying to create a solution which one project is the `.exe` and the other project is a simple `dll`. What i am trying to learn is how to link between two projects. I have searched stack-overflow and found really nice answers which I have followed, such as declaring the right header bath on:

> `Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`C/C++`->`General`->`Additional Include Directories`

Then setting the .lib on:

> `Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`Linker`->`Input`->`Additional Dependencies`

I used macros to generate that `.lib` file also. Here is the my simplified code:

The `.exe`: 
cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication2/HelloWorld.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    hello_world hw;
    hw.printHello();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The dll:
header:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef is_hello_world_dll
#define hello_world_exp  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define hello_world_exp  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class hello_world_exp hello_world
{
public:
    hello_world();
    ~hello_world();
    void printHello();
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include <iostream>

hello_world::hello_world()
{
}

hello_world::~hello_world()
{
}

void printHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

A note: The solution compiles fine when I don't call `hw.printHello();` however when I do call it, the linker generates :

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall hello_world::printHello(void)" (__imp_?printHello@hello_world@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\usteinfeld\Desktop\Private\Students\Yana\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   ConsoleApplication1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is defined as a free function based on how you wrote it

```
void printHello()
```

It belongs to the class `hello_world` so you should scope it as such

```
void hello_world::printHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling its something like this. I will mark as answer as soon as the time limit is up! Thanks!